# Hausdorff measure finite and positive

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, hausdorff-measure, dimension-theory-analysis

Let $A\subseteq [0,1]^d$ be a Borel measurable set. Let $d_H(A)$ be the Hausdorff dimension of $A$. Let $\mathcal{H}^{d_H(A)}$ be the Hausdorff measure w.r.t to the dimension of $A$.

My question is, in what generality is it true that $\mathcal{H}^{d_H(A)}|_A$ (i.e. restricted to $A$) is a finite and positive measure? I am sorry if this question is trivial, but I have searched in several geometric measure theory books, and online, but haven’t found an answer. All the results I found deal with Hausdorff measure of integer dimension, and restricted to smooth submanifold, and not fractals for some reason.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there some specific sort of examples you are interested in?  I would not expect that there is any useful necessary and sufficient criterion in general.

Comment: By definition, the Hausdorff measure is positive, since the diameter of any set is nonnegative. Or did you mean strictly positive? As for whether the Hausdorff measure of $A$ is finite, I believe this holds from $A$ being a subset of a compact set.

Comment: @EricWofsey, hmm I do have a specific example, in the context of hyperbolic dynamics. Specifically, I would like to characterize some equilibrium states, by conditional measures on unstable leaves. I would like for these measures, to be the Hausdorff measure on the set of hyperbolic points in the unstable leaf, w.r.t. to their Hausdorff dimension. I have some heuristics to why I think this should be possible. I understand this may be a completely not-helpful answer, but that’s the setup in which I am interested.

Comment: @Math1000 thanks for the tip. So just to make sure I understand, the Hausdorff measure of dimension 1/2 on [0,1], gives [0,1] a finite measure? It’s a nice property which hasn’t clicked for me before (I’m just now trying to learn about these constructions). Regarding the other part of your answer- yes, I meant strictly positive.